# How can I start the coroutine with time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerMouthSpeechController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text[] texts;
    public bool startTalking = false;
    public float talkTime;
    public float duration;
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public float valueRange;
    private SkinnedMeshRenderer bodySkinnedMeshRenderer;
    //private bool isTalking = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bodySkinnedMeshRenderer = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        /*if (startTalking && isTalking)
        {
            StartCoroutine(AnimateMouth());
            StartCoroutine(TalkTime());

            isTalking = false;
        }

        if(startTalking == false && isTalking == false)
        {
            isTalking = true;
        }*/
    }

    //Lerp between startValue and endValue over 'duration' seconds
    private IEnumerator LerpShape(float startValue, float endValue, float duration)
    {
        float elapsed = 0;
        while (elapsed < duration)
        {
            elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            float value = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, elapsed / duration);
            bodySkinnedMeshRenderer.SetBlendShapeWeight(0, value);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    //animate open and closed, then repeat
    public IEnumerator AnimateMouth()
    {
        while (startTalking == true)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(LerpShape(0, valueRange, duration));
            yield return StartCoroutine(LerpShape(valueRange, 0, duration));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator TalkTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(talkTime);

        startTalking = false;
    }
}
```

I messed it all before with too many flags and in the Update() messed it too.

I want to make something simple. To be able to call from any other script to the method AnimateMouth and that the method AnimateMouth will also get a float will be the time the mouth will be animated. something like :

```
StartCoroutine(AnimateMouth(4f));
```

but I messed it all. maybe to make the AnimateMout public static or when calling from another script first to make a reference to the PlayerMouthSpeechController and then call it something like :

```
playerMouthSpeechController.AnimateMouth();
```

and something will start the AnimatedMouth coroutine. but again I messed it too much.

Update :

This is working almost perfectly as I wanted still I need to use StartCoroutine each time I want the player to start talking but it's working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerMouthSpeechController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text[] texts;
    public float duration;
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public float valueRange;

    private bool startTalking = false;
    private SkinnedMeshRenderer bodySkinnedMeshRenderer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bodySkinnedMeshRenderer = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    //Lerp between startValue and endValue over 'duration' seconds
    private IEnumerator LerpShape(float startValue, float endValue, float duration)
    {
        float elapsed = 0;
        while (elapsed < duration)
        {
            elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            float value = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, elapsed / duration);
            bodySkinnedMeshRenderer.SetBlendShapeWeight(0, value);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    //animate open and closed, then repeat
    public IEnumerator AnimateMouth(float TimeToTalk)
    {
        startTalking = true;

        StartCoroutine(TalkTime(TimeToTalk));

        while (startTalking == true)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(LerpShape(0, valueRange, duration));
            yield return StartCoroutine(LerpShape(valueRange, 0, duration));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator TalkTime(float TalkTime)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(TalkTime);

        startTalking = false;
    }
}
```

And using it for example in another script :

At the top :

```
public PlayerMouthSpeechController blendShapeController;
```

And

```
StartCoroutine(blendShapeController.AnimateMouth(10f));
```

I wish I could do somehow that I will not start a coroutine each time and that it will start the coroutine automatic and I will only do :

```
blendShapeController.AnimateMouth(10f);
```

And it will start the coroutine in the PlayerMouthSpeechController.

Answer (score 1):

Working solution as I wanted :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerMouthSpeechController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text[] texts;
    public float duration;
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public float valueRange;

    private bool startTalking = false;
    private SkinnedMeshRenderer bodySkinnedMeshRenderer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bodySkinnedMeshRenderer = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    //Lerp between startValue and endValue over 'duration' seconds
    private IEnumerator LerpShape(float startValue, float endValue, float duration)
    {
        float elapsed = 0;
        while (elapsed < duration)
        {
            elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            float value = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, elapsed / duration);
            bodySkinnedMeshRenderer.SetBlendShapeWeight(0, value);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    //animate open and closed, then repeat
    public void AnimateMouth(float TimeToTalk)
    {
        StartCoroutine(StartAnimating(TimeToTalk));
    }

    private IEnumerator StartAnimating(float TimeToTalk)
    {
        startTalking = true;

        StartCoroutine(TalkingTime(TimeToTalk));

        while (startTalking == true)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(LerpShape(0, valueRange, duration));
            yield return StartCoroutine(LerpShape(valueRange, 0, duration));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator TalkingTime(float TalkTime)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(TalkTime);

        startTalking = false;
    }
}
```

In other script/s making a reference :

```
public PlayerMouthSpeechController blendShapeController;
```

And starting

```
blendShapeController.AnimateMouth(10f);
```